# Logistic Regression Using Gradient Descent in R

Tags: r

I am new here. Please pardon me if I am breaking stackoverflow rules.
I am trying to implement logistic regression using gradient descent in R. The results from gradient descent are not matching Newton's method ([solution](http://openclassroom.stanford.edu/MainFolder/DocumentPage.php?course=MachineLearning&doc=exercises/ex4/ex4.html)). I cannot figure out where I am going wrong. Could some please help?
Thanks in advance.

Source dataset: http://openclassroom.stanford.edu/MainFolder/courses/MachineLearning/exercises/ex4materials/ex4Data.zip

This is what I get theta = [-0.2268167,  0.6366124, -0.4850165]
Correct theta values are [-16.37875042   0.14834094   0.15890845]

```
rm(list=ls())

rawdataset <- read.csv("ex4data1.csv") # x1,x2,y -> csv format

dataset = cbind(o = rep_len(1,nrow(rawdataset)), rawdataset)

x = data.matrix(dataset[1:ncol(rawdataset)])
y = data.matrix(dataset[ncol(rawdataset)+1])

iterations = 500
alpha = 0.01

m = nrow(y)
theta = matrix(c(rep(0,ncol(x))),1,ncol(x))

costHistory = matrix(c(0),iterations,1)

for(i in 1:iterations)
{
  predictions = 1 / (1 + exp(-x %*% t(theta)))

  for(j in 1:ncol(x))
  {
    errors = (predictions - y) * x[,j]
    theta[,j] = theta[,j] - alpha * (1.0 / m) * sum(errors)
  }

  predictions = 1 / (1 + exp(-x %*% t(theta)))
  costHistory[i,] = sum(-y*log(predictions) - (1-y)*log(1-predictions))/m
  if (i > 1) {
    if (costHistory[i] > costHistory[i-1]) {
      break  
    }
  }
}
t(theta)
plot(costHistory)
```